# How to access a json array in TypeScript/Angular2+?

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to access the json data. My data is -

```
[{"lhs":["GetBook"],"rhs":["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":
["input"],"rhs":["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["ID"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["output"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["Title"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["Author"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["AddBook"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["GetAllBooks"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":["Book"],"rhs":
["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":
["BookServiceSOAP","GetBook"],"rhs":["output"],"confidence":0.75},{"lhs":
["GetBook","output"],"rhs":["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":
["BookServiceSOAP","ID"],"rhs":["output"],"confidence":0.75},{"lhs":
["ID","output"],"rhs":["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},{"lhs":
["BookServiceSOAP","GetAllBooks"],"rhs":["output"],"confidence":0.75},
{"lhs":["GetAllBooks","output"],"rhs":["BookServiceSOAP"],"confidence":1},.....]
```

When I paste it in onlinejsoneditor.com, I get a proper json output -

[image: JSON output]

But I am unable to access it.

i.e. when i do -

```
  console.log("parsedData[0] = ", parsedData[0]);
```

The output is -

```
  parsedData[0] =  [
```

I want to access its particulars like lhs,rhs,confidence

Comment: i guess you said to do like - console.log("parsedData[0] = "+ parsedData[0]);.... sorry no difference

Comment: Please fork this **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-json-from-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** and replicate your issue and share it across.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-json-from-array-krjown

Comment: I think you are trying to concatenate it using + in the second console statement and it is making it as string

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What are you expecting to get as an Output? Use `,` instead of `+` it should get you the response in a readible format.

Comment: You can access individual elements like this this.parsedData[0].lhs

Comment: the out put of it is  -  [parsedData[0] = [
parsedData[1] = {

Comment: @SiddAjmera... i want to access the first array in the json ..instead i am getting the first charater of the json

Comment: With + output is like parsedData[0] = [object Object]

Comment: With , output is like parsedData[0] =  {lhs: Array(1), rhs: Array(1), confidence: 1}

Comment: use  this.parsedData[0].lhs  to access the lhs of the first item

Comment: @dileepkumar .... the output i get is -> parsedData[0].lhs =  undefined

Comment: You should use this.parsedData[0].lhs

Comment: @Techdive, check my answer. It should help. The StackBlitz is also added so you can have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `+` as a `console.log` separator will call `toString` on the JSON Object. That's why you're seeing `[object Object]`. Use `,` and you should be good:

```
console.log('First Response: ', this.parsedData[0]);
console.log('First Response LHS: ', this.parsedData[0].lhs);
console.log('First Response LHS\'s 0th Element: ', this.parsedData[0].lhs[0]);
console.log('First Response RHS: ', this.parsedData[0].rhs);
console.log('First Response RHS\'s 0th Element: ', this.parsedData[0].rhs[0]);
console.log('First Response Confidence: ', this.parsedData[0].confidence);
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-json-from-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: sorry siddAjmera... but the o/p i am getting is this - First Response:  [
 First Response LHS:  undefined
 First Response LHS's 0th Element:  undefined
 First Response RHS:  undefined
 First Response RHS's 0th Element:  undefined
 First Response Confidence:  undefined

Comment: Did you check the StackBlitz? It seems to work in there. You probably are fetching this data from somewhere asynchronously and printing these values even before the values from the async call have resolved. Please make sure that you're not doing that.

Comment: Thanks SiddAjmera for the response. I did Json.parse twice and it worked.